# How to find the best rotation matrix between two Gaussian random variables?

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, rotations

My question is really simple, given two paired sets of points $\{x_i\}$ and   $\{y_i\}$ defined in an N-dimensional space $\{(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), ..., (x_n,y_n)\} \in {\rm I\!R}^N \times {\rm I\!R}^N $, it is possible to find the best translation vector and rotation matrix that transforms $\{x_i\}$ to $\{y_i\}$ using the [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm). To my understanding, this algorithm is purely geometrical and does not suppose any distribution for the random variables $X$ and $Y$ generating respectively $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_i\}$.

Now, given that condition ($\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_i\}$ both have a multivariate Gaussian distribution), is there another version of the Kabsch algorithm that takes such hypothesis into account ? Or is there another technique to find the best translation / rotation vector between data points generated by multivariate Gaussian random variables ?

Any pointer would be of big help. Thanks !

Comment: Hi, minimizing the squared error (which to Kabsch algorithm does) is equivalent to maximize the likelihood given the datas have gaussian distribution, so the answer is that the Kabsch algorithm already does that.

Comment: That's what bugged me, there is no indication that the two are "equivalent" in the proof of Kabsch. He does not make any assumption regarding the distribution of the two data sets.

Comment: in my opinion, **everytime you have a least square criterion**, you can reformulate it as the maximum likelihood for a certain class of gaussian distribution (sometimes with an apriori making it more complicated than a simple quadratic function).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, there is a paper called [Empirical Bayes hierarchical models for regularizing maximum likelihood estimation in the matrix Gaussian Procrustes problem](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1664551/) which reformulates the Kabsch algorithm (solving the Procrustes problem) using a ML estimator supposing the data are generated by a Gaussian distribution.